# i need to add a link to a single image that already has a change source function

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am trying to add a link to a single image that already has a change source function attached to it.

The site has a gallery that uses thumbnails to change the larger image so there are 27 images. I am triyng to add an individual link to one of this images.

all the code i am finding uses id's and in order to keep the change source function working, none of these solutions will work.

The link is for only one image. Here is my code:

```
    <script>function changeImage27()
    {
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.src="thestudio/thestudio_27.gif";
    }
    </script>
```

And my HTML:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
    <img id="image" src="thestudio/thestudio_1.gif" />
    </div>

    <a id="clickme" onClick="changeImage();"><img border="0"src="thestudio/thestudio_1t.gif"></a>
```

I only need to link one image. so i am looking for a solution that adds a hyperlink in the script. a.href="" is not working and i cant seem to find any other solutions.

Comment: the onClick event is called `changeImage()` while the function is defined as `changeImage27()` - is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a better solution:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var images = ["image1.gif","image2.gif",...,"image27.gif"];
var thumbs = ["image1t.gif","image2t.gif",...,"image27t.gif"];
var basePath = "thestudio/";
var currentImage = 0;

function changeImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    var thumb = document.getElementById("thumb");
    img.src = basePath + images[currentImage];
    thumb.src = basePath + thumbs[currentImage];

   currentImage ++;
    if (currentImage >= images.length) {
        currentImage = 0; // this will cause it to loop
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="changeImage();">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img id="image">
    </div>
    <a onClick="changeImage();" href="#"><img border="0" id="thumb"></a>
</body>
```

So you don't have to have 27 different functions.

You could also define the images like follows:

```
var images = [{image:"image1.gif",thumb:"image1t.gif"},...{image:"image27.gif",thumb:"image271.gif"}];
```

Then in changeImage:

```
var image = images[currentImage];
img.src = basePath + image.image;
thumb.src = basePath + image.thumb;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Take a look at this JSFiddle I put together for you.
Cheers!

http://jsfiddle.net/douglasloyo/aR83b/

```
    <script>
    window.changeImage = function changeImage()
    {

       var img = document.getElementById("my-img");
       var newImgSrc = "http://www.johnlund.com/ArticleImages/Artcl38-stock-ideas/dog-leader-pack.jpg";
       img.src=newImgSrc;
    }
    </script>

    <img id="my-img" src="http://www.johnlund.com/ArticleImages/Artcl38-stock-ideas/ocean-island- palm.jpg" />
    <button onclick="window.changeImage();">ClickMe</button>
```